# If $\tau$ is a vector topology on a normed space s.t. a closed ball is $\tau$-compact, is a continuous function on a closed ball even uniformly cont.?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, uniform-continuity, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb K=\mathbb C$, $r>0$, $X$ be a normed $\mathbb K$-vector space, $\tau$ be a vector topology on $X$ s.t. $\overline B_r^X(0):=\{x\in X:\left\|x\right\|_X\le r\}$ is $\tau$-compact and $h:E\to\mathbb C$ be $\tau$-continuous on $\overline B_r^X(0)$, i.e. the restriction $\left.h\right|_{\overline B_r^X(0)}$ of $h$ to $\overline B_r^X(0)$ is continuous with respect to $\left.\tau\right|_{\overline B_r^X(0)}=\{\Omega\cap\overline B_r^X(0):\Omega\in\tau\}$.

> Are we able to show that $h$ is uniformly $\tau$-continuous on $\overline B_r^X(0)$?

Let $\varepsilon>0$. By assumption, for all $x\in\overline B_r^X(0)$, there is an open $\left.\tau\right|_{\overline B_r^X(0)}$-neighborhood $N_x$ of $x$ with $$\forall y\in N_x:|h(x)-h(y)|<\varepsilon\tag1.$$ Since $\overline B_r^X(0)$ is $\tau$-compact, there is a finite $F\subseteq\overline B_r^X(0)$ with $$\overline B_r^X(0)\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in F}N_x.\tag2$$ But at this point I'm stuck ...

Comment: If $X$ is finite dimensional, then copy the proof you know in $\mathbb R$ (according to minor modification). If $X$ is infinite dimensional, then the result is not true (since $B_r^X(0)$ is not compact).

Comment: @Surb $\overline B^X_r(0)$ is not norm-compact, but $\tau$-compact. Do you still think the claim is not true? This seems to contradict Henno Brandsma's answer below.

Comment: @Surb note that he assumes the compactness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a general fact in any uniform space that a continuous function on a compact subset is uniformly continuous on that subset. Nothing specific to topological vector spaces.

Comment: I'm not familiar with uniform spaces. Could you provide a proof or point me to a reference for the particular situation described in the question?

Comment: Your answer is in conflict with the comment of Surb below the question. Did you or is he missing something?

Comment: @0xbadf00d any good topology book covers this result, IMO. You don't need uniform spaces per se, metric proofs also exist in abundance. Munkres covers the metric case.

Comment: You mean metric *vector* spaces? Which chapter/theorem (in which book) of Munkres do you've got in mind?

Comment: @0xbadf00d just general topology. There is a general theorem when he covers uniform continuity. You wanted it for a normed space, so everything metric applies.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look in it. I've actually got a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4018868/47771. Maybe you can help there as well?!